# What are the differences amongst 「ならびに」, 「かつ」 and 「および」?

Tags: grammar, particles

In which situations can I choose one of them to use?

Comment: It is good topic but why are you confused? (Can you add some examples where you think they are interchangeable / you can't see the difference?)

Answer (score 5):

## According to a dictionary...

#### 1. ならびに

> `ならびに` ([接続]{せつぞく}):  [二]{ふた}つの[事柄]{ことがら}を[結]{むす}び[付]{つ}けて，[並列]{へいれつ}の[関係]{かんけい}にあることを[表]{あらわ}す。および。また。

(From Daijirin Dictionary)

Translation:

> `ならびに` (Conj.): Used to express that two things are connected and linguistically parallel. *Similar* to `および` and `また`.

#### 2. かつ

> `かつ` ([副]{ふく}): 二つのことが[同時]{どうじ}にまたは[相前後]{あいぜんご}して[行]{おこな}われることを表す。
>
> `かつ` (接続):  二つの[動作]{どうさ}・[状態]{じょうたい}が[並行]{へいこう}あるいは[添加]{てんか}して行われることを表す。

(From Daijirin Dictionary)

Translation:

> `かつ` (Adv.): Used to express that two thing are done concurrently or near time.
>
> `かつ` (Conj.): Used to express that a thing fulfills two conditions.

## My opinion

#### 1. ならびに, および

`ならびに` and `および` are written language usually.
And they are also used in polite and formal speech especially in a scene that someone speaks to audience.
In ordinary talk, `と` or `それと` can be used instead.

In most cases, `ならびに` can be replaced with `および`, `また`, and `さらに`.

Example (On a event in a school, the principal is speaking to audience):

```
[地域]{ちいき}の[皆]{みな}さん、ならびに[保護者]{ほごしゃ}の[方]{かた}におかれましては、ご[足労]{そくろう}[頂]{いただ}きありがとうございます。
(I would like to thank local residents and parents (of the students) for coming our school.)
```

above is equal to:

```
1. 地域の皆さん、および保護者の方におかれましては、ご足労頂きありがとうございます。
2. 地域の皆さん、また保護者の方におかれましては、ご足労頂きありがとうございます。
3. 地域の皆さん、さらに保護者の方におかれましては、ご足労頂きありがとうございます。
```

#### 2. かつ

Daijirin says that `かつ` are used as both conjunction and adverb but I can't classify how it is used in many sentences. `かつ` can be used in ordinary, speak or polite language.
The certain thing I know is that `ならびに` and `かつ` have different meanings.

Things and conditions connected with `かつ` are fulfilled at the same time.

Example:

```
[彼]{かれ}は[笑]{わら}い、かつ[踊]{おど}った。
(He laughed and danced.)
```

And also it's used in math / programming.
If I want to pronounce `A ∩ B = C` (Set theory),

```
A かつ B [は]{wa} C
```

If I want to pronounce `if(a == b && c == d)` (C programming language),

```
1. もし a イコール b かつ c イコール d なら
2. もし a は b に[等]{ひと}しく、かつ c は d に[等]{ひと}しいなら
```

## Thus

- `ならびに` and `および` can be used when you want to write polite sentences.
- `ならびに` and `および` can also be used when you speak to audience.
- `かつ` can be used when you want to describe two conditions that are fulfilled at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

They all translate to `and` in English. But, in Japanese, they are translated differently depending on how it is used.

**および（及び）**

This is used when listing items. E.g. `A, B, and C` translates to `A、BおよびC`

**ならびに（並びに）**

This is used when listing items that contain a subset of items.

Let's say there are 3 groups A, B, and C. Also, let's say each group has another three items. If you want to list all of them, it would be `A1,A2およびA3, B1,B2およびB3ならびにC1,C2およびC3`.

**かつ**

There aren't any rules like those above. My impression is that `かつ` is used when you need some emphasis. For example, I get the impression that `AかつB` means A *must* be true, *and* B *must* also be true. On the other hand, `AおよびB` simply means A and B.

**と**

This also means `and`. This word can be used in both formal and informal context, but you probably don't often see it being used in legal documents. It is preferable to use `および`.

By the way, you may also come across `または`, `もしくは`, and `あるいは`. These all mean `or` in English. Just like the ones above, `または` is for flat lists, `もしくは` is for nested lists (but you use `または` to connect nested lists), and `あるいは` is neither and can be used in both context.